# Move from default server block on nginx

Tags: nginx, ubuntu-14.04

I setup my server and running Ubuntu server 14.04 with Nginx & php-fpm

When I set everything up I used the default server block `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default`

With my files `/var/www/public_html`

Since my site is fully operational and working as I want I am wary about touching things now.

It is apparent that I now need a different server block for a sub domain as I have all my traffic being redirected to `https://`

How would I carry with configuring now making sure I didn't mess everything up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `nginx.conf` should have a line like this:

`include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;`

This means all configurations in that directory will be included by nginx. Currently, `default` is in this directory, probably symlinked from `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default`. To add a new subdomain with minimal change to existing configuration, just add a new configuration (you could use the old `default` file as a starting point) to `/etc/nginx/sites-available/` and then symlink it to `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled`.

Comment: Thank you I knew it would be as easy as that I couldn't find any relevant information on google that explained in that detail. Or maybe I didnt really know what I was looking for. Now it makes sense thank you